# How to commit and rollback data after getEntityManager.perist(object)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, fluent-nhibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

Now I am using jpa with hibernate , when i was done getEntityManager.persist(objects) then i will ask for user confirmation like continue and rollback using user interface

```
private List<TempCustomers> tempCustomer =new ArrayList<TempCustomers>();

 @Begin(join = true)
    public String migrateData() {

    log.info("Mobee Migrate Customer Size  :"+doTempCustomers.size());




            for(DoTempCustomers tempCustomers:doTempCustomers){
            try {

                TempCustomers temp=new TempCustomers();
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(temp, tempCustomers);


                tempCustomer.add(temp);
                getEntityManager().persist(temp);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                return "null";
            }

             }
            log.info("Size........."+tempCustomer.size());
            return "null";
    }

@Begin(join = true)
    public String updatedData(){
         log.info("Size of Customers :"+tempCustomer.size());
         log.info("Decision ..."+decision);

        try{    
       if(decision.equals("Continue")){
        for(TempCustomers tempCust:tempCustomer){

            TempCustomers temp=new TempCustomers();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(temp, tempCust);   

            log.info("updated Sucessfully");

           getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();

       }}else{
           getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();

        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
}
```

please help me how to do continue and rollback in jpa with hibernate when getEntityManager().persist() is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To commit with JPA:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

To rollback with JPA:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
```

Call either of these methods after your call to persist to perform the desired action.  In your case `entityManager` would be replaced with the call to retrieve the entityManager, `getEntityManager()`

**Reference:** http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/store

Comment: thank you,i have one more doubt in above code i done the migrateData() in getEntityManager.persist(temp); i need rollback commit all data in updateData() method bec i am call request updateData() method from UI can you please tell how can i write code this senario.